# Django show opencv histogram into template

Tags: python, django, opencv, histogram

I'm using **Python 3.6** and **Django 1.11** with **opencv**.

What I want to achieve is, user will upload a photo and then on a new function based action I'll show the uploaded image histogram on rendered template. I've done the following so far:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def show(request, id=None):
  instance = get_object_or_404(Album, id=id)
  img = cv2.imread(instance.photo.path)
  color = ('b', 'g', 'r')
  for i, col in enumerate(color):
    histr = cv2.calcHist([img], [i], None, [256], [0, 256])
    plt.plot(histr, color=col)
    plt.xlim([0, 256])

  # here plt.show() will open a new window with the histogram.
  # but I want to show that plt histogram to the below rendered 
  # show.html template
  context = {
    'title': 'Detail',
    'instance': instance,
    'histogram': # here i want to pass the histogram as image
  }
  return render(request, 'album/show.html', context)
```

In my **album/show.html** I want to show the histogram like:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{ --define histogram src here-- }}"
               alt="Card image cap">
```

Does anyone have any clue how to achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:**

You could save the histogram first:

```
plt.savefig("album/temp_histogram.png")
```

Then modify your album/show.html, you can change the src to the temporary histogram image like:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="temp_histogram.png" alt="Card image cap">
```

**Option 2:**
There is another way to do it. You can draw the figure first, and then convert the image to string, and pass it to your HTML:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.canvas.draw()

# convert canvas to image
histogram_img = np.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8, sep='')
histogram_img = histogram_img.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))
# img is rgb, convert to opencv's default bgr
histogram_img = cv2.cvtColor(histogram_img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
import base64
img_str = base64.b64encode(cv2.imencode('.jpg', histogram_img)[1])
```

Hopefully it helps.

Comment: It creates a image in the folder and then I need to fetch the image (I don't want to save the image). Can't I just create the image on the fly and recreate each time during the function call?

Comment: Sure. But since I don't have the full code to test, I will add some pieces for you to debug or test :)

Comment: I added your edited code. There is an error `main thread is not in main loop`. You can see my update code here: https://repl.it/repls/FunnyFirmMode

Comment: It is very strange, have you tried the first option? Is the histogram image saved correctly?

Comment: yes, the image saved correctly. Should I add your previous code + edited code in my code? Have you seen the repl link which contains my current code?

Comment: No. Option 2 should work without adding the code from option 1. It seems error is from fig.canvas.draw()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177159/discussion-between-emu-and-howard-geng).